# Cannot resolve symbol SpringApplication

Tags: spring, maven

Hi I've created a new spring boot project via intelliJ's Spring initializr

Here is my screenshot:

[image]

It seems something wrong, I've tried "invalid caches and restart", but it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Verify that spring-boot-<version> dep is well loaded in your maven local repo.

Comment: /.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot, there is a folder named [2.0.0.RELEASE]

Comment: Make sure that the .jar exists. Else, remove it and maven update or mvn clean install your project.

Comment: This other SO answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52633454/26535

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Please try:

1. Close IntelliJ
2. delete  .idea/libraries internals
3. delete spring boot libraries from maven
   m2 folder. for example - .m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/

You can find .m2 folder under your home directory.

4. Start IntelliJ
5. right-clicked pom.xml Maven > Reimport

If above steps do not work -

Try

**File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Invalidate And Restart**

Comment: Those folders don't exist

Comment: Just deleting `.idea` folder was helpful for me. And then regenerating it.

Comment: STEP 3 - You can find .m2 folder under your home directory.

Comment: Maybe it will help someone: none of these helped me but deleting cache and restarting intellij. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52633454/5924640