# Does Maven or Gradle Installation occurs automatically?

Tags: maven, gradle, intellij-idea

There is something that has been puzzling me since yesterday,

Yesterday I installed Intellij IDEA on my mac and proceed to do a very simple hello world with spring boot. It worked fine.

Today I am trying to do the same in a windows 10 machine and I am finding a series of issues. It does not work. While investigating why this is happening I find that *neither maven nor gradle is installed in the machine*!

But wait a minute! I did not install any of them (on purpose) on my mac either. Why can I use these installed in the mac but not on the windows 10 machine. Are these automatically installed for some reason.

(just for information the win10 uses a proxy while the mac does not)

---

EDIT:

I have been asked to provide information about the error. 
The original error is *exactly the same* as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52633342/cannot-resolve-symbol-springbootapplication-intellij-dea/52633454#52633454) but I am afraid to ask it and gets flagged as "duplicate question", eventhough the answers on that question don't work at all.

The problem is that after importing a Spring Initializr build to IntelliJ the SpringApplication cannot be resolved. Doing what the answers suggest, solve *temporarily* the problem but as soon as you touch the file again, the problem comes back.

I tried the answers provided in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49364261/cannot-resolve-symbol-springapplication) (that is try `mvn clean install`) and that is when I realized that maven was not installed in my system. Therefore the question I am asking here. Is maven installed automatically?

EDIT 2 In the night I tried it in my mac and yes Gradle is downloaded before running the first time. This does not happen in my windows 10 system. Does running behind a proxy has anything to do? I vaguely remember that I setup the proxy for IDEA too....

EDIT3: Turns out that this problem does not occur with Gradle. however I need to set the proxy in Gradle and I don't know how to do it... (the IDE is configured already)

Comment: Eclipse usually comes with a bundled Maven, I don't know how IntelliJ handles this.

Comment: @JFMeier Oh! I would like to know that. (incidentally, on a complete different project, I have installed Eclipse for C/C++ in my mac... I wonder if that has anything to do)

Comment: You do not need to install Maven or Gradle specifically to with with Maven/Gradle project in IntelliJ IDEA. It provides them for you (in case of a Gradle it downloads it before running for the 1st time and the Maven comes bundled with the IDE). The question does not contain any information about the error. Please specify the exact problem/error you see.

Comment: @Andrey I edited the question to provide the original problem

Comment: Looks like you need to configure proxy to allow you to download libraries. In IDE you configure it in [HTTP proxy](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-http-proxy.html) settings.

Comment: I checked and the proxy is setup. I am trying all the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905896/intellij-inspection-gives-cannot-resolve-symbol-but-still-compiles-code so far all fail :(