# Intellij compilation error because of classpath issues

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have multiple maven microservices under a parent directory.
I loaded all of them in a same intellij window.
I can run all in the same time of them and the microservices work.
The issue is that intellij displays lots of compilation errors, whereas the projects compile.

I tried removing my local .m2 repository, reimport all maven projects then invalidate cache and restart, the compilation errors remains.

Errors are :

```
Cannot access org.reactivestreams.Publisher
Cannot access org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext
Cannot resolve symbol 'Qualifier'
```

and suggestions are:
add library maven... to classpath for some of them, but for others no suggestion

I use last version of intellij.
The project uses spring boot, java 11 and maven

Comment: *I loaded all of them in a same intellij window.* ... I have no idea what that is supposed to mean. Dont "explain" how you supposedly configured your project. Rather include the relevant details, either .iml file content, or worst case: screenshots.

Comment: Please provide sample project example demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot resolve symbol SpringApplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49364261/cannot-resolve-symbol-springapplication)

Comment: the answer was incomplete as I had to reimport all project then, but yes, 1st I has to do this (was not enough to fix issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally (after 2 days) fixed the issue, after the followings steps:

1- Delete .iml and .idea files

2- Open new intellij project, then add all projects as new modules from existing sources

3- Let intellij detect for each module the spring boot services